# Is there a way to check for return code using PSFTP?

Tags: batch-file, psftp

I am creating a script file using windows BATCH and then calling it using PSFTP (using Putty from command line to call TransferScript.txt).

The requirement is to get a file from Unix box to windows and then delete it from Unix but after getting the return 0. My code looks like:

TransferScript.txt

```
lcd E:\Temp 
cd /sap/xx/yy 
get abc.dat 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQ 0
rm abc.dat
quit
```

This doesn't work, however file is getting copied but not getting deleted. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The command processor for the file is `psftp`, not `cmd.exe`.  As such, `IF` is not a recognized command.  You can, however, use the `!` `PSFTP` command to pass commands to Windows.  This is [documented here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.66/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-pling).  Here is a tested working version:

Command: `psftp -b script.txt username@ftpserver.com -pw password`

```
#script.txt
!echo Connected. Getting file...
lcd c:\temp 
cd sap/xx/yy
get abc.dat
!IF EXIST c:\temp\abc.dat echo Success
!IF NOT EXIST c:\temp\abc.dat echo Failure
quit
```

Simply replace `echo Success` with `rm abc.dat` or whatever you want to happen if the file exists on the local file system.

Another option would be to do all the logic in an external batch file.  Write 2 `PSFTP` scripts like script_get.txt and script_rm.txt and call the second one only if the file exists (like above).

I know neither of these solutions technically answer your question in that they don't capture an error state from `PSFTP` but hopefully it's an acceptable workaround.